# How to update datatype in Big query table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have just started my POC in Big Query. I would like to know how to update/modify the column definition/schema  in an existing table.

bq mk -t market.cust custid:integer,grp:integer,odate:string
bq update -t market.cust custid:string,grp:integer,odate:string

```
**Error:
spanda2040@instance-3:~/data$ bq update -t market.cust custid:string,grp:integer,odate:string
BigQuery error in update operation: Provided Schema does not match Table arboreal-height-175822:market.cust. Field custid has changed type from INTEGER to STRING**
```

Table Schema:

Last modified          Schema         Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration   Time Partitioning   Labels

---

02 Oct 13:38:29   |- custid: integer   0            0
                    |- grp: integer
                    |- odate: string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SELECT will incur some co$t as you will need to scan the whole table

Below is super simple approach that costs $0.00

1. Export your existing Table into GCS
2. Load from GCS to new Table with same schema as your original table with exception of that column to be of fixed type
3. You done. $0 cost!!

I just did this to sanity-check and it works as a charm

when you will get comfortable with this approach  - you can even load into the same table - with WRITE_TRUNCATE for writeDisposition property

Comment: That's one way to do.But https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#append-overwrite says Issue the bq update command and provide the schema definition:
 bq update [DATASET].[TABLE] [SCHEMA]. I wonder why its not working.

Comment: You can update the schema for an existing table by adding new fields to it. The new fields must be NULLABLE or REPEATED. You cannot add a REQUIRED field to an existing table schema. - So, when documentation says about updating schema they looks like mean adding new field(s). - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#update-schema

Comment: I see.bq mk -t market.cust1  custid:string,grp:integer,odate:string
bq update  market.cust1 custid:string,grp:integer,odate:string,custid1:string worked for me but bq update  market.cust3 custid:string,grp:string,odate:string,custid1:string is throwing error. I believe it should allow. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Run a query that replaces the existing table with the results of a query that casts the data as you'd like:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a, b, c, CAST(d as INT64) AS d
FROM `p.t.d`
```

Update, based on comment - If I want to change an integer to string:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a, b, c, CAST(d as STRING) AS d
FROM `p.t.d`
```

Comment: I would like to update the table structure.Let's my column is  integer but I want to change it to string. IN Normal sql we write the alter table..

Comment: I added a sample on how to change a integer to a string in BigQuery. Just overwrite your table with the results of this query.

Comment: See market.cust custid:integer. I can't insert a string value to the cust id (value is CU101). So I have to change the structure of the table. Traditional SQL:ALTER TABLE table_name. ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype; Big Query: bq update -t market.cust custid:string,grp:integer,odate:string.. It's throwing error

Comment: Yes. Don't do that. `bq update` won't work on this case. Instead do a `SELECT ...` as shown in the answer, and materialize those results. That will work.